# Synchronize offline SQLite database with online MySQL database

Tags: android, mysql, android-studio, android-sqlite

I'm creating a Android application that store the data in online backend *MySQL* and store it in app `sqllite`. Which means when user is online, data sync with online backend database to sqlite database. When user offline, so he/she can use the sqlite data.is this proper way? Or what I can do to better solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using Sync Adapters.

Checkout how it works in the following link and go further on the documentation for more info.

https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html

Comment: Like when user offline the data store in sqlite database with flag ,when user online the system check for the flag and sync with the server right ? I did it in my previous application I need better solution is that Sync Adapter new to me

Comment: Practically, what you do is always use the local database (sqlite), but when the user has internet access, you sync the databases.This way you don't "use" the user's mobile internet (if he has wifi access,that won t be a problem) and the application will be faster, since everything is local.Obviously, you use the data from local, but your requests or whatever you do with the data will go online, to your services.

Comment: As per you said I store everything in offline , when do I sync with online and how to sync with online server on background without user interaction ?

Comment: I am not completely sure about that, but I am confident there is a method in the sync adapter.After all that's exactly what it's doing.You don't need to stop everything while offline, you just cannot interact with the server.What you could do,is store in sqlite every action that would normally require interaction with the server and once the user goes online, ask if it's ok to do what he wanted to do while he was offline.Or ask him even before that,while he is offline (something like "you are offline, but when you will have internet access, the application will do everything automatically).

Comment: When user online how do I upload the data from sqlite in background here check it out my application www.personaldiaryapp.com I'm working on the update for this application , the probulm is when I'm online asyntask is displaying with progress dialog which may let the user interaction loading feeling , how do I sync the sqlite database into online database in background ?

Comment: I have to do some digging on my own on that but I am at work at this moment.I will be back with an answer as soon as I can.You should check the methods available on sync adapters, I am pretty sure you got something there.